# NSAppleScript Wont Work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript

Can someone please tell me why this won't work?

```
NSAppleScript* playPause = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:
    @"\
    tell application \"System Events\"\n\
     tell application \"Final Cut Pro\" to activate\n\
     keystroke \" \"\
    end tell"];
```

I get the error "Expected ':' ',' ';' '}' or '**attribute**' before '=' token".  WTF?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Putting a backslash before the newline inside a string literal **does not work** in C, Objective-C, or C++.

Just use

```
NSAppleScript* playPause = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:
    @"tell application \"System Events\"\n"
    @"    tell application \"Final Cut Pro\" to activate\n"
    @"    keystroke \" \""
    @"end tell"];
```

using automatic concatenation of string literals.

Comment: The syntax is no longer a problem, but when i use

[playPause executeAndReturnError:nil];

nothing happens.  Is there a better way to execute the appleScript?

Comment: Does the script itself work? I don't have FCP so I can't test it myself. And I think I forgot `\n` after keystroke, sorry about that. I would  keep the script in a separate file and use `-[NSAppleScript initWithContentsOfURL:error:]` instead.

Comment: You don't need to repeat the `@`, `@"Hello " "World" is enough.